# How to get bluetooth RSSI on android after connection

Tags: android

I'm trying to write a program that can read the signal

strength(RSSI) of a bluetooth device linked to my APP

however

Doesnt seem like android exposes anyway to get the RSSI while it is during discovery.

Is there any other way to get the signal strength of the device after the device has been

linked(not pairing)

Any help would be appreciated.